# HttpClient post with Content-Disposition

Tags: android, post, apache-httpclient-4.x

Good evening.

Usually I'm working with post request like that`name1=value1&name2=value2` and my code is

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name1", "value1"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity("name2","value2");
```

But now I have the post like that

```
-----------------------------17911109517875 Content-Disposition: form-data;
name="PERSON*1[F*2][2664]" value1 
-----------------------------17911109517875 Content-Disposition: form-data; 
name="PERSON*1[I*3][2776]" value2 
-----------------------------17911109517875 Content-Disposition: form-data;  
name="PERSON*1[O*4][2778]" value3
```

So, as far as I know, I should do

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PERSON*1[F*2][2664]", "value1"));
```

But what with content-disposition ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to utilize HttpClient's HttpMime support. This is not included out of the box with Android so you will have to bundle it with your application.

An example, based on your post could be accomplished as follows:

```
    MultipartEntity mpe= new MultipartEntity();
    FormBodyPart part1= new FormBodyPart("PERSON*1[F*2][2664]", new StringBody("value1"));
    FormBodyPart part2= new FormBodyPart("PERSON*1[I*3][2776]", new StringBody("value2")); 
    FormBodyPart part3= new FormBodyPart("PERSON*1[O*4][2778]", new StringBody("value3"));
    mpe.addPart(part1);
    mpe.addPart(part2);
    mpe.addPart(part3);
```

An example of the above output to a stream would be as follows:

```
--ZV5t1WLAh04TJTqjyBJBSDL3M69xu0A
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="PERSON*1[F*2][2664]"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

value1
--ZV5t1WLAh04TJTqjyBJBSDL3M69xu0A
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="PERSON*1[I*3][2776]"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

value2
--ZV5t1WLAh04TJTqjyBJBSDL3M69xu0A
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="PERSON*1[O*4][2778]"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

value3
--ZV5t1WLAh04TJTqjyBJBSDL3M69xu0A--
```

I believe the library is more or less stand-alone and can be retrieved from the httpclient website.

Comment: which dependency are you using??