# How to send body text field along with files in Android POST multipart form data

Tags: android, http-post, multipartform-data

I'm trying to post an image along with some text fields to a server. I'm following the following code to POST the file to server, and its working fine. But I'm not able to figure out where to send the text field.

```
public class TaskPostData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;
        String existingFileName = file_path;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        String urlString = "http://my/post/url";
        try {
            InputStream fileInputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\";filename=\"" + upload_file_name + "\"" + lineEnd); // uploaded_file_name is the Name of the File to be uploaded
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }

        try {
            inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            String str;
            while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);
                reponse_data = str;
            }
            inStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Every part of a multipart is in between two boundary lines. So add a new Content-Disposition line also.

Comment: @greenapps: please give a small example code. I've 18 fields to be sent along with one image.

Comment: Well give it a try. An show your tries in this post.

Comment: Look at the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320886/httpclient-post-with-content-disposition to see how your output should look like. Every parameter with it's value goes between boundaries.

Comment: @greenapps: Thanks a lot. Finally made it work. your last comment was really helped.

Comment: @downvoter: Please explain the down vote. As without explanation of down vote, it's worth less.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String POST_PARAMS = "userName=Pankaj";
```

here is how i would add

```
dos.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
```

Comment: But where to add those lines?

Comment: Good question. Sanny's solution will only work without an image.